# Prove $a<b$ iff $a^r<b^r$ for $a,b\in\Bbb R^+$ and $r\in\Bbb Q^+$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm really stuck on this question. My intuition is:

> Assume $a<b$. By the uniqueness theorem, there exists a unique $y$ such that $a^r=y$, or $a=y^\frac1r$. Similarly for $b^r$ we have $b=z^\frac1r$ where $y,z\in\Bbb R$. Since $a<b$, this implies $y^\frac1r<z^\frac1r$.

And I'm stuck. I feel like I'm going about it the wrong way and that there should be a much simpler solution.

For the reverse direction, my proof is as follows:

> Assume $a^r<b^r$. By uniqueness, we know $a^r=y$ and $a=y^\frac1r$, and similarly for $b$. Then $a^r<b^r$ can be rewritten as $y^\frac1r<z^\frac1r$, which is $(a^r)^\frac1r<(b^r)^\frac1r$. Then $a<b$.

Comment: Consider $a=-1$, $b=0$, and $r=2$.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! It seems I missed some stuff in the title. It should be $0<a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. I apologize and thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I don't know if this is understandable to you, but since $f(z)=z^r$ is a one-to-one function and monotone increasing for $z,r\in\mathbb R^+$, then by the epsilon delta method, $a^r<b^r$ for $a<b$.

Comment: Can you prove it first for integer exponents? Then if you write $r = m/n$ with $m,n$ positive integers, you have $a<b \Leftrightarrow a^m < b^m \Leftrightarrow (a^r)^n < (b^r)^n \Leftrightarrow a^r < b^r$.

Comment: @arkeet Interesting! I think this should work

Comment: I suppose it ought to go into an answer.

Comment: @SimpleArt I've not covered the epsilon delta method, but I definitely see what you mean. I suppose I struggle formally proving things - even though the concepts may be simple to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

I have some doubts about whether
$a^r<b^r$ can simply be "rewritten" 
as $y^\frac1r<z^\frac1r$ when $a^r = y$.
It seems to me 
$a^r<b^r$ is rewritten as $y=z$.

I would suggest first proving a version of the theorem in which $0 < r \in \mathbb Z$. You can do this by induction. To prove the more general case $0 < r \in \mathbb Q$,
write $r=\frac pq$ where $p>0$ and $q>0$.
Then you can use the integer-power version of the theorem and the fact that $\left(x^{1/r}\right)^r = x$ to prove the main theorem.

Comment: Is there a reason why rewriting it as $a^{r}=y$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}$ would be wrong? Just asking out of curiosity! 

Nevertheless, I believe what you suggested would indeed give me a nice proof. Thank you!

Comment: The _rewriting_ gives you $y<z$, without exponents. Maybe you inferred  the desired result by applying the previous result about $y$ and $z$, but that relied on a different assumption about $a$ and $b$. It looks circular.

Comment: Oh yes, that was rather silly of me. I think (with a little bit of revision) it will work for the forward direction. Given $y=a^r$ and $y^\frac{1}{r}=a$ and similarly $z^\frac{1}{r}=b$, we have   $a<b \rightarrow y^\frac{1}{r} < z^\frac{1}{r} \rightarrow (y^\frac{1}{r})^r < (z^\frac{1}{r})^r \rightarrow y<z \rightarrow a^r < b^r$. Again, this does seem very circular so I'm not sure. Regardless, I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

If you can first prove it for integer exponents, then write $r = m/n$ with $m,n$ positive integers. Then you have
$$ a < b \Longleftrightarrow a^m < b^m \Longleftrightarrow (a^r)^n <  (b^r)^n \Longleftrightarrow a^r < b^r. $$